# How to add multiple tables to a gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview

Is it possible to add 3 different tables to a gridview that will allow me to insert, edit, update and delete records from an SQL database? If so how can this be done?

Thank you

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: He's using sql server.  The Microsoft only crowd often shorten the name.

Comment: sorry. sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Use one class which has all the required attributes from 3 tables. Use 3 different constructors to fetch data from the database. After that you can create a list of that class type and use it as a data source for your grid view. You can't use this approach if you are using datasets to fetch data from your database. You can write a seperate business ligic layer and call the methods from UI code behind file. You can use ADO.Net to fetch data in your business logic layer.